# Get the attributes value of any class in vb6

Tags: reflection, vb6

I have many  classes with 15 attributes(at least) for each one and I want to build a function that returns a string that contains all attributes. The simple way is to add a this function in each class:

```
Public function getAllAttributes(instance as Object) as String
 Dim str as String
 str = str & “**”& instance. Attribute1 & .... &“**”&  instance. Attribute100
 getAllAttributes = str
End function
```

But I want to build a function that works with all classes(the idea in pseudo code is:)

```
Public function getAllAttributes(instance as Object) as String
 ‘function that handles all classes
 Dim str as String
 For att in instance 
    Str = str & “**”&  att.value
 Next
 getAllAttributes = str
End function
```

I have used typelib information reference, but I was a able to get just the attributes names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it.

Add TypeLib information as a reference to your project.

Then, use these two functions:

```
Public Function CharExecution(pObject As Object) As String
    CharExecution = “”
    Dim TLI         As TLIApplication
    Dim lInterface  As InterfaceInfo
    Dim lMember     As MemberInfo

    Set TLI = New TLIApplication
    Set lInterface = TLI.InterfaceInfoFromObject(pObject)

    Set ClassInfo = TLI.InterfaceInfoFromObject(pObject)
    Set FilteredMembers = ClassInfo.Members.GetFilteredMembers

    For Each lMember In lInterface.Members
        If WhatIsIt(lMember) = "Property Get" Then
            CharExecution = CharExecution & "*****" & lMember.Name & " : " & TLI.InvokeHook(pObject, lMember.Name, INVOKE_PROPERTYGET)
        End If
    Next
    Set pObject = Nothing
    Set lInterface = Nothing
    Set TLI = Nothing        
  End Function

   '================================================================================

 Private Function WhatIsIt(lMember As Object) As String
  Select Case lMember.InvokeKind
    Case INVOKE_FUNC
        If lMember.ReturnType.VarType <> VT_VOID Then
            WhatIsIt = "Function"
        Else
            WhatIsIt = "Method"
        End If
    Case INVOKE_PROPERTYGET
        WhatIsIt = "Property Get"
    Case INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT
        WhatIsIt = "Property Let"
    Case INVOKE_PROPERTYPUTREF
        WhatIsIt = "Property Set"
    Case INVOKE_CONST
        WhatIsIt = "Const"
    Case INVOKE_EVENTFUNC
        WhatIsIt = "Event"
    Case Else
        WhatIsIt = lMember.InvokeKind & " (Unknown)"
 End Select
End Function
```

Call it as:

```
  MsgBox CharExecution( classInstanceName)
```

Or

```
  MsgBox CharExecution(New ClassName)
```

Thanks .